# Deploy work queue in a paused state Prefect 2.0

Tags: python, scheduling, prefect

I'm working in Prefect 2.0 and want to deploy a work pool with some work queues inside. These work queues each contain a specific task. This is the YAML file I'm using for the deployment:

```
###
### A complete description of a Prefect Deployment for flow 'log-flow'
###
name: testing_for_uc4
description: null
version: 681f48004e1f1186a35d451c73c1c414
# The work queue that will handle this deployment's runs
work_queue_name: uc4_test
work_pool_name: uc4_test
tags: []
parameters:
  name: Lars
schedule: null
is_schedule_active: true
infra_overrides: {}

###
### DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
###
flow_name: log-flow
manifest_path: null
infrastructure:
  type: process
  env: {}
  labels: {}
  name: null
  command: null
  stream_output: true
  working_dir: null
  _block_document_id: 877973bc-54aa-4176-8cf9-3a34146a981b
  _block_document_name: anonymous-5ec41c02-049a-4771-beee-d77f49febd48
  _is_anonymous: true
  block_type_slug: process
  _block_type_slug: process
storage: null
path: C:\School\2IMS\Internship\Prefect\uc4
entrypoint: uc4_test.py:log_flow
parameter_openapi_schema:
  title: Parameters
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      title: name
      position: 0
      type: string
  required:
  - name
  definitions: null
timestamp: '2023-05-26T12:22:01.284897+00:00'
```

Is it possible to deploy all of this (in YAML or Python) so that the work queue inside of the newly created work pool is deployed in a paused state? So that the slider below in the UI is turned off:

[image: Click here to view image]

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the rest API documentation to have a more hands [on approach to pause the work pool](https://app.prefect.cloud/api/docs?deviceId=fd2fd5f8-5acd-496f-bec6-daf601caf5b9&deviceId=fd2fd5f8-5acd-496f-bec6-daf601caf5b9#tag/Work-Pools/operation/update_work_queue_api_accounts__account_id__workspaces__workspace_id__work_pools__work_pool_name__queues__name__patch)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).